# Use a global variable in a test enviroment

Tags: java, junit, mockito, guice

i need to know if I can use a global variable on an API in this particular case

I have a class in a lib (i have no access) witch read a message queue (like kafka or rabbit) and post in an elastic search

example:

```
public Class MessageQueue(message) {
    if (isValid(c)) {
        // post in kibana
        onDelivered(message)
    }
}
```

I need to extend this class to add functionality

```
public Class MessageQueueService extends MessageQueue {

    UserRestService userRestService;

    User user;

    @Inject
    public void MessageQueueService(UserRestService userRestService) {
        this.userRestService = userRestService;
    }

    public boolean isValid(message) {
        // first a made if's to discard the message with the message info, to avoid the API call

        //if the message is Valid here
        user = userRestService.get(message.getId);

        //more validation
    }

    public void onDelivered(message) {

        // bunch of code with the user info like: 
        doStaff(user);

        return;
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the correct way to use the global variable **user**, because i can't initialize in the constructor because I may end not using this request. And use an singleton is against the rules I think.

I fail when I try to make the unit test for de onDelivered method because I can't mock the User global variable, and I am kind of lost.

I'm using Java with Guice and JUnit and Mockito for testing! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java reflection to do like this

```
@Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() throws Exception {
        Field field = targetTestObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("shipment");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(targetTestObject, user);
    }
```

Comment: But when I am testing the onDelivered method, I already call the UserRestService in the previous method. How can I do it?

Comment: Yes, thank you so mutch. But it's ok to do this in this way? I mean is not against the rules use global variables to save domain information?

Comment: So you want to run this once to fill the user attributes and keep it to use in other test cases?

Comment: I am going to try this solution! thanks for your help!

Comment: I have an error when I try this solution:
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: No static field named "shipment" could be found in the class hierarchy of com.mercadolibre.services.bigqueue.BigQueueShipmentsService.

I don't need to mock a static field!

Comment: The field is called `shipment` and Is it declared as final?

Comment: I can't make it final because I need to instantiate in the middle of the isValid class. to avoid unnecessary API calls! And the field is called shipment!

Comment: Ok, see the update version using `reflection`, hope this works!